# Smooth scrolling through components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to smooth scroll my landing page, I tried different npm like smooth scrollbar but its not working. How do I smooth scroll when there are different components? This is my landing page.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ParallaxProvider } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
import MainSlider from '../components/MainSlider';
import Find from '../components/Find';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';
import Adoption from '../components/Adoption';
import BreedServices from '../components/BreedServices';
import Brand from '../components/Brand';
import AdoptionFaq from '../components/adoption/AdoptionFaq';
import AdoptionShop from '../components/AdoptionShop';
import Testimonial from '../components/Testimonial';
import BlogsHome from '../components/BlogsHome';

function Home() {
    return (
        <main>
            <ParallaxProvider>
                <MainSlider />
                <Find />
                <Counter />
                <Adoption />
                <BreedServices />
                <Brand />
                <AdoptionFaq/>
                <AdoptionShop />
                <Testimonial />
                <BlogsHome />
            </ParallaxProvider>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your css

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Comment: I also tried that but its not the thing that I want, like I wanted to use the smooth scrollbar but it doesn't do anything in my code I've added this `const containerRef = useRef();

 useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect is running');
  const container = containerRef.current;
  console.log('Container:', container);

  Scrollbar.init(container, {
   damping: 0.01,
  });

  return () => {
   Scrollbar.destroy(container);
  };
 }, []); <main ref={containerRef}>`  but its not working